# Vue.js and paginate

Tags: vue.js

any guidance appreciated. In using paginate within a vue filter I mess up my other filters. I have copied some of the code to this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ashleywnj/kbr0obsv/2/

With paginate added as a filter, on line 23 in the HTML section, it disables the search and the ability to sort by clicking on the column headings.

```
<tr v-for="item in items | filterBy searchText | orderBy sortparam order |     paginate">
```

If you delete the paginate filter within the fiddle you will see that you can sort and search ... I have brought each value to the console - it looks like everything is good both with or without the paginate filter, consequently I can't figure out how to fix this or what I may have missed.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that within your `paginate` filter you are using `this.items`, which contains all of the items in your list, regardless of the other filters.  The argument called `list`, passed to the filter, contains only the filtered and ordered values, and is what you want to paginate.  So your filter would look like this:

```
paginate: function(list) {

        this.resultCount = list.length;

        if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages) {
          this.currentPage = Math.max(0, this.totalPages - 1);
        }

        var index = this.currentPage * this.itemsPerPage;

        return list.slice(index, index + this.itemsPerPage);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363283/how-to-display-content-by-page-number-or-prev-next-clicked-on-the-vue